# Chaining jQuery promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I wish to call `dealCardSelectableAI()`, have it `chooseCards()`, then use the output to set an observable `system.star.cardList()`, then call `setCardName()`. Once all this is done I want `saveGame()` to execute.

However, `setCardName()` is not completing before `saveGame()` is called, so apparently I can't push it into my deferredQueue via a `.then()`.

I'm using jQuery due to working within an ES5 environment.

```js
var setCardName = function (system, card) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  require(["cards/" + card[0].id], function (data) {
    var cardName = loc(data.summarize());
    system.star.ai().cardName = cardName;
    deferred.resolve();
  });
  return deferred.promise();
};

var dealCardSelectableAI = function (win, turnState) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  // Avoid running twice after winning a fight
  if (!win || turnState === "end") {
    var deferredQueue = [];

    _.forEach(model.galaxy.systems(), function (system, starIndex) {
      if (
        model.canSelect(starIndex) &&
        system.star.ai() &&
        system.star.ai().treasurePlanet !== true
      ) {
        deferredQueue.push(
          chooseCards({
            inventory: inventory,
            count: 1,
            star: system.star,
            galaxy: game.galaxy(),
            addSlot: false,
          }).then(function (card) {
            system.star.cardList(card);
            deferredQueue.push(setCardName(system, card));
          })
        );
      }
    });

    $.when(deferredQueue).then(function () {
      deferred.resolve();
    });
  } else {
    deferred.resolve();
  }

  return deferred.promise();
};

dealCardSelectableAI(false).then(function () {
  saveGame(game, true);
});
```

I tried resolving this by changing the function calls so `setCardName()` was chained following `dealCardSelectableAI()`. However, it relies on `system.star.cardList()` having been written, which in some circumstances had not yet been done.

Given the dependency `system.star.cardList()` has on `chooseCards()`, I cannot figure out how to make sure it has been written to before calling `setCardName()` in a way which blocks `saveGame()` until everything is done.

Comment: Do you really need to use jQuery for this? Native Promises are more flexible and (IMO) a lot easier to deal with - I don't see you using jQuery for anything else in the code either

Comment: apparently using underscore/lodash for a single line of code as well. Yikes.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm stuck in an ES5 environment., no native promises for me.

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Simply do `return setCardName(system, card);` instead of `deferredQueue.push(setCardName(system, card));` so that the `.then()` promise you're pushing to the `deferredQueue` is fulfillled when the inner `setCardName` promise fulfills. It seems you're ignoring the result values anyway so it shouldn't matter what value you resolve the promises with.

Comment: @Bergi I'm afraid I've tried that, but it doesn't appear to work, `saveGame()` is still called before `setCardName()` has returned.

Comment: @Quitch Again, which version of jQuery are you using? You might need to call `pipe` instead of `then`

Comment: @Bergi, apologies, I missed that. I am using 2.1.4